# Remote login with curl (php)

Tags: php, validation, curl, authentication

I try to submit login form with phpcommand: curl, but it doesn't work.
The fields form are two: email and psw.
The problem is that if I use urlencode to field email it return the error: "incorrect format email!", while if I not use the urlencode there aren't response.

This is the code without urlencode:

```
$url = 'myurl';
$fields = array(
        'login_email'=> 'myemail@gmail.com',
        'login_passwd'=> 'mypsw',
    'remember_me' => '1'
    ); 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Return page in string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
echo $page;

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: ...well, obviously, we'd need to see the code that's handling the logins...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure there's no response? Many login systems simply do a redirect to some other page if the login is successful. Try adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

which'd let CURL obey the redirect and fetch whatever page the server's sending you off to.

Alternatively, you can use the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option to include the HTTP headers in the response returned into your `$page` value and see what's going on there.

Comment: I obtain the solution!!! I use this class: http://www.sv-design.org/blog/php-classe-curl-come-gestire-le-richieste-e-i-login-remoti-con-php/